# I have BIP39 mnemonic and need BIP44 xpub

Tags: mnemonics, xpub

I have a 12 words valid mnemonic phrase and I need to get it's Bip44 
Extended Public Key so I can check if it had past transactions.

I wasn't able to find any explanation/documentation on how to get what I need or how the process works (or maybe I'm too dumb to understand) so I guess if someone who's experienced could give me some simply explained directions I could appreciate it.

Comment: What network/blockchain are you on? Bitcoin, Ravencoin, Ethereum etc?